# The train had left the station when I arrived (there)

Tags: idiomatic-language

> (1) The train had left the station when I arrived.
> (2) The train had left the station when I arrived **there**.

**Question:** Which sentence sounds natural to native English speakers' ears?

I don't know which sentence is natural because, in Japanese, we normally say

> (3) When I arrived at the station, the train had left.

Comment: They are both fine but correcting answers is not really allowed here. [English speakers' ears]

Comment: You can say the same thing in English as (3). You might consider using *before* instead of *when* in the first two. In (2) 'there' is superfluous.

Comment: We *have* to include ***there*** in the alternative phrasing *The train had left the station when I **got there***. But idiomatically, we're far more likely to express that as *The train had **already** left the station **by the time** I got there*.

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers. Is it OK to use "get there" in formal speech and writing? Some Japanese teachers of English say that the verb "get" often sounds informal.

Comment: Yes, _arrived_ sounds more formal than _got there_.  _There_ is superfluous after _arrived_ because it's obvious that the speaker means _at the station_.

Answer (score 2):

They are both fine.

(1) sounds better than (2), and it would sound even better if you added the word **already**:

> The train had **already** left the station when I arrived.